# change layout on selection box change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prototype

I want to render a partial depending on a selection in selection box. This looks trivial but I can't find an example.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: It depends on how you want to determine which partial to render, or in other words, you need to determine what happens when you "select" something. Do you mean selecting something, clicking a button and being redirected, or rendering something in-line via ajax when selecting something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're simply trying to render a partial on the page that the form submits to,

```
<%= render :partial => params[:your_selectbox_value_matching_the_partial_you_want] %>
```

So if you had a select box like

```
<select name='the_partial'>
    <input value="partial1">Some Partial</input>
    <input value="partial2">Another Partial</input>
</select>
```

You'd need to render

```
<%= render :partial => params[:the_partial] %>
```

Assuming you have _partial1.html.erb and partial2.html.erb in your view folder

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with something like this:

```
app/views/_layout_selector.html.erb:
<form action="<%= request.request_uri -%>">
  <select name='layout'>
    <input value="blue">Blue</input>
    <input value="pink">Pink</input>
    <input value="green">Green</input>
  </select>
</form>

app/views/layouts/blue.html.erb:
<html>
  ...
  <%= render :partial => '/layout_selector' %>
  ...
</html>

(/app/views/layouts/pink.html.erb and green.html.erb similar)

app/controllers/application.rb:
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  DEFAULT_LAYOUT = 'blue'
  layout :pick_layout
  ...
  private
  def pick_layout
    params[:layout] || DEFAULT
  end
end
```